# False word elemination using Regex replacement

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to perform content/keyword based search in a list of files. for that i need to extract the `keywords` and store them in `MySQL` database. the key words are extracted in following manner:

- Read the file content
- Remove special characters and additional white spaces if any using

  `Regex.Replace(input, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", " ")`
- Remove `am/is/are/be/being/been/` , `have/has/having/had/`, `do/does/doing/did/` `adjectives`, `phrases`, `Adverbs` etc..
- Removing endings like :

  ```
  -IC-ATION   fortification
  -IC-ITY     electricity
  -IC-MENT    fantastically
  -AT-IV      contemplative
  -AT-OR      conspirator
  -IV-ITY     relativity
  -IV-MENT    instinctively
  -ABLE-ITY   incapability
  -ABLE-MENT  charitably
  -OUS-MENT   famously
  ```

Can i do the whole operation using a single `Regular expression`? is their any simplest method for this? [Here](http://xapian.org/docs/stemming.html) i have a reference algorithm for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible to implement a stemming algorithm using regular expressions exclusively. Maybe you should take a look at already existing implementations to get ideas. [Here is a link to the Porter stemming algorithm in VB.net](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/vbnet.txt)